# exclude spring oauth2 configuration

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

Is there any way exclude AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration from spring boot ?

I try different configuration but its not working

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can only use the `exclude` in `EnableAutoConfiguration` for classes that are declared in `spring.factories`. Check your `spring.factories` file(s) for the closest Autoconfiguration class you have to `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration`, which I think is `OAuth2AutoConfiguration`.
If you want to "partially" autoconfigure `spring-security-oauth2` that can't be done. You'd have to do the opposite, "partially" manually configure oauth2, that means that you have to exclude the entire autoconfiguration and create whatever configuration you need.